# How to monitor system timezone changed in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In iOS I can listen `NSSystemTimeZoneDidChangeNotification`.

What should I do in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Finally my solution is remember and compare system timezone everyTime  AppState `didChangeAppLifecycleState` changed to `resumed` .